# How can I make this quick sort partition balanced and not include pivot the next loop?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I implemented the quick sort partition method using two ways :

The first is the classic Hoare partition scheme. It's efficient (two partitions are balanced, as we always use `<` or `>` instead of `<=`) but it does not return the pivot directly :

```
private static int partition(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    int p = arr[lo];
    int i = lo - 1;
    int j = hi + 1;
    while (true) {
        while (arr[--j] > p) ;
        while (arr[++i] < p) ;
        if (i >= j) {
            return j;
        }
        swap(arr, i, j);
    }
}
```

The second one is an easier to understand version as it returns directly the pivot, and the pivot does not come into two partitions. But I cannot figure it out how to remove the `<=` in this line `while (i < j && arr[i] <= p) {` :

```
private static int partition(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    int p = arr[lo];
    int i = lo;
    int j = hi;
    while (true) {
        while (i < j && arr[j] > p) {
            j--;
        }
        while (i < j && arr[i] <= p) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i >= j) {
            break;
        } else {
            swap(arr, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, lo, i);
    return i;
}
```

So is it possible to have a two-way partition method that is at the same time efficient (without any equal sign) AND the pivot will not be included into partitions the next loop ?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem), which describes a partitioning algorithm where all elements equal to the pivot end up together between the left and right partitions.

Comment: @user3386109 ok but I want first to solve it properly using 2-way quicksort

Answer (score 1):

You just have to leave the partition at the right place.  So don't include it in your partitioning, then swap it in to your known correct place at the end.

```
private static int partition(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    int p = arr[lo];
    int i = lo;
    int j = hi + 1;

    while (true) {
        while (arr[--j] > p) ;
        while (i < j && arr[++i] < p) ;
        if (i >= j) {
            // arr[j] <= p, and arr[lo] is still p.
            swap(arr, lo, j);
            return j;
        }
        swap(arr, i, j);
    }
}
```

Note that your second version had an extra comparison in every iteration of the loop.  That should matter more than the relative costs of `<` vs `<=`.  (Which I doubt are significantly different.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I test your code but it seems not to be working, the array I used for testing is : [7, 0, 7, 4, 6, 4, 7, 9, 3, 7]

Comment: or to be simpler if the input arr = [9,7,7], we will have i throws error 
 : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @hawarden_ The second was a bug, now fixed.  The first example looks like it updates the array to `[3, 0, 7, 4, 6, 4, 7, 9, 7, 7]` and returns `6`. This is correct behavior. The pivot is at 6, everything left is <=, and everything right is >=. Used in a quicksort, the pivots on either side will find their way to the right spot.